# How do I correctly implement this dependency in a mutlti module project?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

So I'm trying to break a large project up into modules but after adding a new module gradle gives this error `Failed to resolve: :api-1:
Affected Modules: member_module`.

api-1 is used in the app build.gralde like so.

```
dependencies {
    // Add dependency for Snap external API
    implementation(name: 'api-1', ext: 'aar')
. . . .
```

The Snap api is a library module in our project.

how do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [official docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#AddDependency).

1. To use your Android library's code in another app module, proceed as follows:

   - Add the compiled AAR (or JAR) file (the library must be already built):

     1. Click File > New > New Module.
     2. Click Import .JAR/.AAR Package then click Next.
     3. Enter the location of the compiled AAR or JAR file then click Finish.
   - Import the library module to your project (the library source becomes part of your project):

     1. Click File > New > New Module.
     2. Enter the location of the library module directory then click Finish.

The library module is copied to your project, so you can actually edit the library code. If you want to maintain a single version of the library code, then this is probably not what you want and you should instead add the compiled AAR file as described above.

2. Make sure the library is listed at the top of your settings.gradle file, as shown here for a library named "my-library-module":

```
include ':app', ':my-library-module'
```

3. Open the app module's build.gradle file and add a new line to the dependencies block as shown in the following snippet:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":my-library-module")
}
```

4. Click **Sync Project with Gradle Files**.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using the following dependency line:

```
implementation(name: 'api-1', ext: 'aar')
```

it means that you want to use an `aar` file as dependency, which is different with your intention.

> The Snap api is a library module in our project.

You need to add the library module to your main module.
**First**, check if you have include the library in **settings.gradle** and make sure you have the following line:

```
include ':api-1'
```

**Second**, add the library module as dependency with the following line:

```
implementation project(':api-1')
```

**Last**, build the app.